# Highcharts.js - edit the axis of a chart without remaking it

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart with numerical values on the X-axis, and I would like to "shift" its contents to the right, i.e. I want to increment each of the X-axis values by 1. I know that, in theory, I can just remove my current chart and make another one with the augmented X-axis, but is there another way without that step, somehow dynamically editing the axis values?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding if this has to do with the axis or the points? You just want the points to stay in place, and edit the labels/values on the axis? Or do you want your points to get 1 added to their x-value, and the x-axis to represent that afterwards?

Comment: @Halvor those two would do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use add point method. refer http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint

```
 chart.series[0].addPoint();
```

[demo fiddle from highchart API](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-addpoint-append-and-shift/)